# Estimating Approx. Time A Job Will Take

Tags: python, progress-bar, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a loading bar for Python CLI and I want it to be as accurate as possible.

As such I came up with an idea: why not ask Python to estimate how long the job will take (hashing a file md5 and SHA1).

But searching it returned nothing - most, if not all, tutorials taught how to create a progress bar that progresses by time, not literal progress.

Thank you all in advance!

P/S: I think it helps a lot more to let you all know I am using Python 2.7

Comment: May be kinda impossible while the time Python will need for something is based on the power of the PC/CPU/GPU/Other tasks running

Comment: How would you *know* how long it *should* take? Based on what information? [Necessary xkcd](http://xkcd.com/612/)

Comment: I mean... Say if we put "based on the power of the PC..." aside, the size of the file is the only main reason the time will vary

Comment: If you are only worried about time based on size of file then you can easily use very many of the posted solutions in Stack Overflow. Just add a "square" of progress every certain part that has been processed. Let's say 10% of the file has been copied then add 1/10 squares...etc

Comment: Alright. I finally understood what the BLOCKSIZE = 65536 means and I believe I can make use of it. Thank you so much.